# CSS Absolute Position Causes Font Re-size In Google Dev Tools

Tags: css, google-chrome

Guys I have very strange issue and I am not sure whether it is related to CSS or Chrome itself.

I have been working on a web site when discovered that if I am on mobile preview, and positioned a block as absolute, the font inside the block display very little on the screen.

Please screenshots:

Position absolute enabled:

[image]

Position absolute disabled

[image]

I have removed all styles and scripts to test it, same issue.

Currently the code I have is shown below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        div{
            position: absolute;
            color: red;
            font-size: 16px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum .... </p>
    <div>TEXT</div>
</body>
</html>
```

P.S. Tested on latest versions of Chrome and Chrome Canary - same issue.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: working perfectly [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mEJJBZ), we need more code to help you

Comment: strange, for me too.. but it doesn't work locally

Comment: all the code I have currently I have posted

Comment: just try to open any site, even jsfiddle. remove all element using the devtools, then paste the code I have and switch to mobile view. same issue

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue, it was because missing viewport metatag...

If someone is having such issue, just add the string below to the head tag of your HTML:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1>
```

Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use vw instead of px.

```
font-size: 10vw;
```